# Using JavaBean with JasperReports API: Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException after obfuscation

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, obfuscation

Well, my application contains more than 100 class files. The entire application work's fine without being obfuscated, but after obfuscating the application using ***ProGuard*** I'm getting a strange exception:

```
JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : ID
        at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrin
t(JasperReportBuilder.java:319)
        at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.show(JasperR
eportBuilder.java:332)
        at ims.d.aA.done(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(
Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value
 from bean : ID
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProp
erty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldVal
ue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldV
alue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDat
aset.java:1330)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.jav
a:1231)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.jav
a:1207)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:
1544)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVertic
alFiller.java:142)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:
909)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:
841)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.
java:653)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillMa
nager.java:969)
        at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrin
t(JasperReportBuilder.java:308)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ID' on class 'clas
s ims.Reports.Item'
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(Prop
ertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(Prop
ertyUtilsBean.java:762)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUt
ilsBean.java:837)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.
java:426)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProp
erty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
```

Below is the bean class that is being pointed :

```
public class Item {

    private String id;
    private double quantity;
    private double unitprice;
    private String uom;
    private String iname = null;

    public String getID() {
        try {
            String query = "select name from master where company_code='" + ims.MainWindow.cc + "' and inid='" + this.id + "'";
            // System.out.println(query);
            Connection con = CPool.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                iname = rs.getString(1);
            }
            CPool.closeResultSet(rs);
            CPool.closeConnection(con);
            CPool.closeStatement(st);
        } catch (Exception x) {

        }
        return iname;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.id = ID;
    }

    public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getUnitprice() {
        return unitprice;
    }

    public void setUnitprice(double unitprice) {


        this.unitprice = unitprice;
    }

    public String getUOM() {
        return uom;

    }

    public void setUOM(String u) {
        this.uom = u;
    }
}
```

I've tried keeping the related class'es names, methods, tried to prevent them from shrinking.

What are other open source *obfuscator* alternatives I can use?

Comment: Have you contacted the folks who support the obfuscation software?

Comment: Have you checked the JasperReports forums?

Comment: if you have any additional library, this causes problem sometimes. But still it should work till obfuscation level 8.

Comment: try to change the get/set method `getID/setID` to `getId/setId`

Comment: JasperReports uses `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils` to get property value, and PropertyUtils works via reflection. Obfuscator changes bean getters/setters name, so it becomes impossible to get its value with reflection using old names.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used jasper reports for a long time but it looks like it is using the [java beans convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) to get the data. If you obfuscate your java beans, it will no longer be possible to find a getter for the attribute ID by the building the name getID().

I would suggest excluding such classes from the obfuscation.

Comment: This would be obvious I think... He should accept this...